# Trigger - Difference in FOR/AFTER/INSTEAD OF

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I need to rebuild following section on a trigger:

```
{ FOR | AFTER | INSTEAD OF }
```

So if the trigger has "`instead of`" it could be 0 or 1:

```
SELECT
 is_instead_of_trigger  
FROM sys.triggers
Where object_id = Object_Id ('')
```

How can i resolve if the particular trigger has `for` or `after`?

Comment: `FOR` and `AFTER` trigger is the Same thing.

Comment: thanks bro yeah is the same

Comment: pleasure :)    ............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are Two types of Triggers,

1. `Instead Of` Triggers that fires Instead of the Triggering action
2. `After or For` Triggers that fires after the Triggering action.

Catalog View `sys.triggers`'s column `is_instead_of_trigger` will tell you whether is an Instead of trigger or not, if value `0` then it is `For or After Trigger`, if value `1` then it is an `Instead of Trigger`

Answer (score 1):

I believe **after** and **for** are the same thing.

It's either instead of, and is_instead_of_trigger will have 1 as value. Or (FOR | AFTER) for 0.

[CREATE TRIGGER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx)

FOR | AFTER
AFTER specifies that the DML trigger is fired only when all operations specified in the triggering SQL statement have executed successfully. All referential cascade actions and constraint checks also must succeed before this trigger fires.
AFTER is the default when FOR is the only keyword specified.
AFTER triggers cannot be defined on views.